# Getting Properties of a Running Program

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I would like to develop a program which ID's a card as it is played in another running program such as a poker or hearts game or whatever. I'm starting by trying to get the information I need on that game program which is already running, and I'm having problems right from the start. I'm running MSVC++ 2013 and developing an MFC application. Right now I'm playing with the Hearts game and here's the code:

```
HWND hwnd =  FindWindowA(NULL, "Hearts");
if (hwnd == NULL)
    {  /* window not found*/
    }
else
    {  /* window was found */
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }
```

So I get hwnd just fine and the code works depending on whether I have Hearts open or not. But the line `GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);` won't compile saying

> "error C2660: 'CWnd::GetWindowRect' : function does not take 2 arguments".

There is a `GetWindowRect` function which only has the rect argument, but gets the properties of the program window I'm working on. There is lot's of documentation on `GetWindowRect` which shows the two arguments as above, but how do I invoke that subroutine?

Answer (score 5):

As you are inside an MFC window class, you are calling the `CWnd::GetWindowRect` function - you want to call the one in the Win32 API, so:

```
::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
```

where the `::` scope resolution operator (without a namespace or class name on the left-hand side) says to call the function in the global scope.