# What does the :: mean in m_hAccel = ::LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDR_ACCELTEST));

Tags: c++

What does the `::` mean? in:

```
m_hAccel = ::LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDR_ACCELTEST));
```

Comment: global scope operator -- google it. It's used all the time in MFC (that's MFC code you posted). Basically it's purpose is to pull from the global scope where all the native Win32 API is defined since MFC reimplements a lot of the Win32 API to use MFC classes. That code is saying "don't use MFC's implementation, use the native Win32 API implementation."

Comment: See, for example, this question (and it's answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/50608812/10871073